# Kingston USB flash drive is empty, yet properties show half-full, and data disappears?

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, laptop, memory

My USB flash drive was empty but the properties show half full. I don't want to format it because I saved my wedding pictures in the pen-drive, and those were gone. Hidden files does nothing.
 How can I get my picture back?

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like your USB drive has a corrupted filesystem or is damaged, try checking it for errors, and if this doesn't help try [PhotoRec](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/PhotoRec).